# Is there an RPG for Iain M Banks' setting of The Culture?

Tags: game-recommendation, campaign-settings, science-fiction

And if not, what would you recommend using? I've always thought it would make for some interesting gaming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There hasn't been a formally released Culture game, no. However:

- Joshua Newman's [Shock: Human Contact](https://twitter.com/Burning_Luke/status/4277044875632640) is designed as a Culture-like game.
- [Diaspora](http://www.vsca.ca/Diaspora/) is a hard-science fiction game, based on FATE.
- Most interesting and speculative of all, [Luke Crane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luke_Crane_%28game_designer%29), who wrote Burning Wheel, has [announced he's acquired a licence](https://twitter.com/Burning_Luke/status/4277044875632640). From the way he's announced it, it could be the Culture. Let's hope.

Comment: Thanks Graham, particularly for the Luke Crane rumour. That would be *very* interesting!

Comment: oooh Luke Crane and Culture. Got a link?

Comment: Only the one I gave above. Hardly an announcement.

Comment: The one you gave above just goes to his twitter stream. Is there a specific tweet you had in mind?

Comment: Just added the three relevant tweets to the main for ya, Graham, Sohum.

Comment: Thank you. I've actually changed that to a link to the original tweet, rather than reproducing the tweets.

Answer (score 5):

An unofficial Champions/Hero System adaptation has been done.

Its original website is missing, but it is archived at [http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.sden.org/jdr/spaceopera/download/GB/IainBanks.pdf](http://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://www.sden.org/jdr/spaceopera/download/GB/IainBanks.pdf)

as of this writing, the link works.

Comment: Nice find, thanks! Bit of an odd system choice in some ways (I would have thought a high crunch level was asking for trouble in such a hi-tech setting with huge scale) but I've saved a copy anyway, and who knows, someone else may find it ideal.

Comment: Hero really isn't all that high-crunch, no worse than GURP or Traveller. It also has vehicle, base, and AI creation rules. The supplement adds no rules, just hows how to apply the extant ones.